# WSO2 AM HTTP Endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have an issue when using HTTP Endpoint in WSO2 AM,

```
<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
<ams:code>900906</ams:code>
<ams:message>No matching resource found in the API for the given request</ams:message>
<ams:description>Access failure for API: /rest/v1, version: v1. Check the API documentation and add a proper REST resource path to the invocation URL</ams:description>
```

However, it is working if using Address Endpoint,

[image: Address Endpoint info]

[image: Address Endpoint Impl]

Change to HTTP Endpoint that is not working,

[image]

Comment: Error log says no matching resource found. Please make sure you append the resource path which you have defined in publisher for GET request.

Answer (score 1):

Note that "No matching resource found" error is related to dispatching your API request to the correct API and resource. Hence it does not have any relationship with your endpoint type.

According to the attached screenshots, your API context and version is MrlDatabaseAPI/v1. But what you have tried is rest/v1. If you do not have an API with context as "rest" and version as "v1", then you will get this type of error. If you want to invoke MrlDatabaseAPI/v1 API, then also make sure you append the correct resource path to that (/pesticides, /report, /reportNotes, /crops, /cuntries).

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific so others may be able to help you, such as what version of AM, what end points work and what not, what is "Address Endpoint"?

Per your snapshots, it looks like it will point to /rest, NOT /rest/v1 .

Answer (score 0):

You can enable WIRE logs and analyze this further. Address Endpoint and HTTP Endpoint both works in a similar manner. Follow [this](http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html) to enable WIRE logs in API Manager.